# I am not sure how this loop for finding positive and negative data set will work out to give me a the confusion matrix. Any suggestion?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

Code:

```
import nltk
eng_lish= open("english.txt","r", encoding='utf-8',errors="ignore").read()
bang_lish= open("banglish.txt","r", encoding='utf-8',errors="ignore").read()
import numpy as np
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)),
                     ('nb', MultinomialNB())])
classif = SklearnClassifier(pipeline)
pos_data= [FreqDist(nltk.word_tokenize(bang_lish))]
neg_data= [FreqDist(nltk.word_tokenize(eng_lish))]
print (pos_data)
print (neg_data)
pos=[FreqDist(pos_data.words(f)) for f in pos_data.append('pos')]
neg=[FreqDist(neg_data.words(f)) for f in neg_data.append('neg')]

#from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
#pos = [FreqDist(movie_reviews.words(i)) for i in movie_reviews.fileids('pos')]
#neg = [FreqDist(movie_reviews.words(i)) for i in movie_reviews.fileids('neg')]

add_label = lambda lst, lab: [(x, lab) for x in lst]
classif.train(add_label(pos[:100], 'pos') + add_label(neg[:100], 'neg'))

l_pos = np.array(classif.classify_many(pos[100:]))
l_neg = np.array(classif.classify_many(neg[100:]))
print ("Confusion matrix:\n%d\t%d\n%d\t%d" % (
          (l_pos == 'pos').sum(), (l_pos == 'neg').sum(),
          (l_neg == 'pos').sum(), (l_neg == 'neg').sum()))
```

Error:

```
>C:\Users\Nouros\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/Nouros/Desktop/Thesis/nltk_run_copy.py
[FreqDist({'?': 312, '.': 182, 'er': 122, 'na': 122, '...': 101, 'ki': 92, 'o': 62, '!': 59, 'ta': 56, 'e': 56, ...})]
Traceback (most recent call last):
[FreqDist({'.': 6972, 'the': 5060, 'a': 3842, 'and': 3553, 'of': 3311, 'to': 1970, "'s": 1813, 'is': 1776, 'it': 1674, 'that': 1357, ...})]
  File "C:/Users/Nouros/Desktop/Thesis/nltk_run_copy.py", line 20, in <module>
    pos=[FreqDist(pos_data.words(f)) for f in pos_data.append('pos')]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is comming from this line:

```
pos=[FreqDist(pos_data.words(f)) for f in pos_data.append('pos')]
```

the one below it will throw the same error though

```
neg=[FreqDist(neg_data.words(f)) for f in neg_data.append('neg')]
```

The issue is that `in pos_data.append('pos')` returns `None` and you cannot write `for f in None`. I am not quite sure what you are intending to to in that line. If you elaborate I can extend my answer

Comment: I am trying to read the both English and banglish text files here to my classifier. So it can give me the confusion rate of banglish and english as in positive and negative format just like the movie review files.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Here is the confusion matrix generate the type to solve this problem,
import nltk
nltk.download('sentence_polarity')
eng_lish= open("English_Comments.txt","r", encoding='utf8' , errors="ignore").read()
bang_lish= open("Banglish_Comments(Thesis).txt","r", encoding='utf8' , errors="ignore").read()[enter link description here][1]

import numpy as np
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)),
                     ('nb', MultinomialNB())])
classif = SklearnClassifier(pipeline)
pos_comments = [FreqDist(nltk.word_tokenize(bang_lish))]
neg_comments = [FreqDist(nltk.word_tokenize(eng_lish))]

add_label = lambda lst, lab: [(x, lab) for x in lst]
classif.train(add_label(pos_comments, 'pos') + add_label(neg_comments, 'neg'))
l_pos = np.array(classif.classify_many(pos_comments[:1000]))  # size 0 to 1000
l_neg = np.array(classif.classify_many(neg_comments[:1000]))
print("Confusion matrix:\n%d\t%d\n%d\t%d" % (
             (l_pos == 'pos').sum(), (l_pos == 'neg').sum(),
             (l_neg == 'pos').sum(), (l_neg == 'neg').sum()))


  [1]: https://pastebin.com/pxyUPb76
```